# How to Navigate 3 tables in EntityFrame work WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I am New to WPF. I has a Country class generated from database using Entity frame work. When I press pageup or pageDown keys navigate to Country class to display Country id and name next elements first to last elements. When i run the code i got Exception please tell me How to navigate 3 tables
My database class:

public partial class Country{

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Country()
    {
        this.PurchaseOrderLineItems = new HashSet<PurchaseOrderLineItem>();
        this.States = new HashSet<State>();
    }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
    public string Country_Code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderLineItem> PurchaseOrderLineItems { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

navigate Businesslogic class is:

public Country NavigateCoutryCodebyID(int countryCodeID, NavigationType nav)
        {

```
        //.Include("State").Include("PurchaseOrderLineItem")
        Country countryCode = null;
        try
        {
            using (LWLLCDBEntities dbEntities = new LWLLCDBEntities())
            {
                //current item
                switch (nav)
                {
                    case NavigationType.First:
                        countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    case NavigationType.Last:
                        countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.OrderByDescending(t => t.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    case NavigationType.Current:
                        countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Where(i => i.CountryID == countryCodeID).FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    case NavigationType.Next:
                        countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Where(i => i.CountryID > countryCodeID).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (countryCode == null)
                            countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    case NavigationType.Prev:
                        countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Where(i => i.CountryID < countryCodeID).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (countryCode == null)
                            countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.OrderByDescending(t => t.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                log.Error("BusinessLogic.NavigateCountryCodebyID in Business Logic threw exception: ", ex);
            }
        }
        return countryCode;


    }
```

i will wrote 
case NavigationType.First: 
countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Include("State").Include("PurchaseOrder‌​LineItem").FirstOrDe‌​fault(); 
break; 
case NavigationType.Last: 
countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Include("State").Include("PurchaseOrder‌​LineItem").OrderByDe‌​scending(t => t.CountryID).FirstOrDefault(); 
break;
 like this also same exception. when i load it will display 247 records. when i navigate this exception raised

Comment: You say you got an exception, but what is the exception telling you?

Comment: NullReference Exception unhandled by User

Comment: i will wrote  case NavigationType.First:
                            countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Include("State").Include("PurchaseOrderLineItem").FirstOrDefault();
                            break;
                        case NavigationType.Last:
                            countryCode = dbEntities.Countries.Include("State").Include("PurchaseOrderLineItem").OrderByDescending(t => t.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
                            break;  like this also same exception. when i load it will display 247 records. when i navigate this exception raised

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information, don't write it in comments.

Comment: Others had already improved your question, you should only add information (with decent formatting!!) and not revert their good changes.